# Python infix to post-fix Evaluation AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, stack

So here's my code:

```
from StackClass import Stack


def postfixEval(postfix):
    os = Stack()


tokenList = postfix.split()

for token in tokenList:
    if token in "0123456789":
        os.push(int(token))
    else:
        op2 = os.pop()
        op1 = os.pop()
        result = doMath(token,op1,op2)
        os.push(result)
return os.pop()

def doMath(op, op1, op2):
    if op == "*":
        return op1 * op2
    elif op == "/":
    return op1 / op2
elif op == "+":
    return op1 + op2
else:
    return op1 - op2



def pres(p):
    if p is '(':
        return 0
    elif p is '+' or '-':
        return 1
    elif p is '*' or '/':
        return 2
    else:
        return 99

def read(p):
    if p is '(':
        return left
    elif p is ')':
        return right
    elif p is '+' or p is '-' or p is '*' or p is '%' or p is '/':
        return operator
    elif p is ' ':
        return empty    
    else :
        return operand                          




def infixtopostfix(infixexp):

    for i in infixexp :
        type = read(i)
        if type is left :
            outlst.append(i)
        elif type is right :
            next = outlst.pop()
            while next is not '(':
                postfix.append(next)
                next = outlst.pop()
        elif type is operand:
            postfix.append(i)
    elif type is operator:
        p = pres(i)
        while len(outlst) is not 0 and p <= pres(outlst[-1]) :
            postfix.append(outlst.pop())
        outlst.append(i)
    elif type is empty:
        continue

while len(outlst) > 0 :
    postfix.append(outlst.pop())


print "It's postfix notation is ",''.join(postfix)
```

## MAIN PROGRAM

while True:

```
postfix = []
outlst = []
operator = -10
operand = -20
left = -30
right = -40
empty = -50


infixexp = raw_input("\nEnter the infix notation : ")
infixtopostfix(infixexp)
print(postfixEval(postfix))   



choice = raw_input("\nDo you want to continue?<1-Yes/0-No>: ")

if choice == '0':
    break
```

I get this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. I don't know where it comes from, i tried stringing the list by using join but doesn't take effect. I felt like I should post this, I need help and also for those who are having problems with this error as well in Stack Implementation and Evaluation.

By the way, in the infixtopostfix(infixexp) part, do you have any idea how I could make the result with spaces on each other? For example: instead of 13+5* make it 1 3 + 5 * . How do i do this? I'm figuring it out right now. I'll answer my own question here. if I solve the problem. But for time effeciency, someone might bump into this and have solved the problem in the past. please do help :) Thanks!

TRACEBACK

Traceback (most recent call last): File "practice.py", line 112, in     print(postfixEval(postfix)) File "practice.py", line 8, in postfixEval tokenList = postfix.split() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace

Comment: Show us the full traceback

Comment: The error is obvious: list object has no split. add 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()' if you don't know what the type of inflixxxxx is.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "practice.py", line 112, in <module>
       print(postfixEval(postfix))
     File "practice.py", line 8, in postfixEval
        tokenList = postfix.split()
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `postfix = []` and `postfix.append(outlst.pop())`
 shows that postfix is a list. A list has no method like `split()`, rather it can be applied on a `str` object.

Comment: So should I make postfix str before then? like this?

        str(postfix)
        tokenList = postfix.split()

I get the same error

Comment: Listen, what is the purpose of split() here? split() returns a list, and you already have that list. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the SPACING problem. Simply split the infix expression after raw_input. That way it would acknowledge for example 100 as one string. The result would then be what I included on my post. Incase you didn't know.